# Convert COBOL data to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, cobol

We received data from COBOL as below, and got to convert to SQL Server. I have followed this [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3459/importing-mainframe-data-including-packed-numbers-with-sql-server-integration-services/)

and did create the SSIS package. However i'm facing issue when converting some data from COBOL to SQL.

I marked the input columns as Bytes and Output as Numeric data as 10 and Precision 2

1.Tried creating columns as Decimal(10,2) in SQL
2.Tried it with SQL date data type for COBOL date

the package runs successfully but data is not populated.
[data layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNCAh.png)

```
CONTRACT-SIZE         pic S9(9)V99 COMP-3         
DIV-REC-DATE-LOBO     PIC  9(0007) COMP-3  
PAR-DATE              PIC S9(0007) COMP-3  
BID-PRICE             PIC S9(0005)V9(2)  COMP-3
```

Tried below function to unpack, Translate, COBOLZonedPicToDecimal

```vb
Public Function Translate(ByVal str As String, sConversionTable As String) As String

    Dim Temp As String, I As Int32
    Temp = Space(Len(str))
    For I = 1 To Len(str)
        Mid(Temp, I, 1) = Mid(sConversionTable, Asc(Mid(str, I, 1)) + 1, 1)
    Next
    Translate = Temp
End Function

Private Function Unpack(ByVal bPacked As Byte(), ByVal iDecimalPlaces As Integer) As Decimal
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim HiNibble As Byte
    Dim LoNibble As Byte
    Dim dResult As Decimal = 0


    For i = 0 To bPacked.Length - 2
        UnpackNibblesToBytes(bPacked(i), LoNibble, HiNibble)
        dResult = Convert.ToDecimal(dResult * 10 ^ 2I + HiNibble * 10 + LoNibble)

    Next
    UnpackNibblesToBytes(bPacked(bPacked.Length - 1), LoNibble, HiNibble)

    dResult = dResult * 10 + HiNibble

    If LoNibble = &HD& Then
        dResult = -dResult
    End If

    Unpack = Convert.ToDecimal(dResult * 10 ^ (-iDecimalPlaces))

End Function

Private Sub UnpackNibblesToBytes(ByVal InputNibbles As Byte, ByRef LoNibble As Byte, ByRef HiNibble As Byte)

    LoNibble = (Me.F And InputNibbles)
    HiNibble = ((Me.F0 And InputNibbles) >> 4)

End Sub

Public Function DecimalToCOBOLZonedPic(ByVal dNumber As Decimal, ByVal iPadLength As Integer, ByVal iDecimalPlaces As Integer, ByVal bModifiedZoned As Boolean) As String
    Dim isNegative As Boolean = False
    Dim strNumber As String
    Dim sPositive As String = "{ABCDEFGHI"
    Dim sNegativeMod As String = "}JKLMNOPQR"
    Dim sNegativeStrict As String = "pqrstuvwxy"

    ' Determine the sign
    If dNumber < 0 Then
        isNegative = True
        dNumber = -dNumber
    End If

    dNumber = Convert.ToDecimal(dNumber * (10 ^ iDecimalPlaces))

    strNumber = dNumber.ToString

    If strNumber.IndexOf(".") > -1 Then
        ' Truncate remaining decimal places
        strNumber = strNumber.Substring(0, strNumber.IndexOf("."))
    End If

    ' Pad with leading zeros
    If strNumber.Length < iPadLength Then
        strNumber = strNumber.PadLeft(iPadLength, "0"c)
    End If

    Dim lastDigit As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(strNumber.Substring(strNumber.Length - 1, 1))

    If bModifiedZoned Then
        If isNegative Then
            strNumber = strNumber.Substring(0, strNumber.Length - 1) & sNegativeMod.Substring(lastDigit, 1).ToString
        Else
            strNumber = strNumber.Substring(0, strNumber.Length - 1) & sPositive.Substring(lastDigit, 1).ToString
        End If
    Else
        If isNegative Then
            strNumber = strNumber.Substring(0, strNumber.Length - 1) & sNegativeStrict.Substring(lastDigit, 1).ToString
        End If
    End If

    Return strNumber
End Function

Public Function COBOLZonedPicToDecimal(ByVal strNumber As String, ByVal decimalPlaces As Integer) As Decimal
    Dim sZoneChar As String
    Dim convertedNumber As Decimal
    Dim sPositive As String = "{ABCDEFGHI"
    Dim sNegativeMod As String = "}JKLMNOPQR"
    Dim sNegativeStrict As String = "pqrstuvwxy"

    strNumber = strNumber.Trim

    If strNumber = "" Then
        Return 0
    End If

    sZoneChar = strNumber.Substring(strNumber.Length - 1)

    Select Case True
        Case sPositive.IndexOf(sZoneChar) > -1
            strNumber = strNumber.Substring(0, strNumber.Length - 1) & sPositive.IndexOf(sZoneChar)
            convertedNumber = Convert.ToDecimal(strNumber)

        Case sNegativeMod.IndexOf(sZoneChar) > -1
            strNumber = strNumber.Substring(0, strNumber.Length - 1) & sNegativeMod.IndexOf(sZoneChar)
            convertedNumber = -Convert.ToDecimal(strNumber)

        Case sNegativeStrict.IndexOf(sZoneChar) > -1
            strNumber = strNumber.Substring(0, strNumber.Length - 1) & sNegativeStrict.IndexOf(sZoneChar)
            convertedNumber = -Convert.ToDecimal(strNumber)
        Case Else
            convertedNumber = Convert.ToDecimal(strNumber)
    End Select

    Return Convert.ToDecimal(convertedNumber / (10 ^ decimalPlaces))
End Function
```

Comment: You don’t give enough information to solve your problem, but I would point out that SSIS code is actually .Net code, so I would recommend creating your conversion code outside of the SSIS package and use debugging and unit test to figure out what is going wrong and where.  While you can debug a SSIS package, it is a pain.

Comment: The COBOL record layout in your question is binary. Is your file EBCIDIC fixed width? Are those the only fields in the file? Add a snippet of the file contents to your question with this PowerShell script:`(New-Object System.IO.BinaryReader([IO.File]::Open("YourFullFilePathHere", [System.IO.FileMode]::Open,[System.IO.FileAccess]::Read,[System.IO.FileShare]::ReadWrite))).ReadBytes(100) | Format-Hex`

Comment: COBOL is a programming language, not an operating system nor a file format.  Some [things to consider](https://github.com/cschneid-the-elder/rants/blob/master/advice-reading-mainframe-data.md) when attempting to download and convert mainframe data.

Comment: Your linked article didn't really explain how they got from the `PIC 9(8)V99` field coding to `decimal(10,2)` in SQL Server, so you should probably read [COBOL Comp-3 Packed Fields](http://www.3480-3590-data-conversion.com/article-packed-fields.html) to understand what your specific field codings mean. e.g.: `S9(9)V99` means `decimal(11,2)` in SQL Server but will still occupy six bytes in the data stream.

Comment: @jmoreno ... i did some testing, trying to put some breakpoints and debug (VB Script). Looks like the way i have defined the output columns data type is creating the issue. I was able read data from the COBOL file which has characters and integer values. Only issue is with these COMP3 data types in COBOL. Not sure, how to get them to SQL Server.

Comment: @DanGuzman ...thanks for your response, however it has very sensitive data. I know, without any sample data it is hard to move ahead. It would be really helpful if i get some help here on how i do unpack of these COMP3 data.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning ... this is my first time and never came across this type of data, so just followed as per link. I been through the link you mentioned, trying to figure out how i could do that. As, the DIV-REC-DATE-LOBO PIC 9(0007) COMP-3 is a date (as per data provided by user) in COBOL and how would i get that into SQL server.

Comment: @Kris, you can scrub or omit all fields in the hex dump of the file except for at least one example of the packed decimal fields. That shouldn't be a concern without data context.  I think that will be the best way to help you since you didn't answer any of the questions I asked.

Comment: @DanGuzman sorry, i missed them. As per data dictionary details provided by the user, the total row length is 820 and there are some 7000 odd rows. I added them in the question above.

Comment: @DanGuzman poweshell o/p...hope this helps
           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   42 33 38 35 36 34 31 30 38 31 30 20 20 02 00 EA  K410810  ..ê
00000010   A4 31 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  ¤1              
00000020   20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20                  
00000030   20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20                  
00000040   20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20                  
00000050   20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20                  
00000060   20 20 20 20

Comment: The characters in the file are ASCII rather than EBCDIC. The only data that is non-character is offset 15, length 3 (0x00EAA4) but that doesn't look like a comp-3 field value left intact from the source system (could be 9(7) comp-3 originally). My guess is an upstream transfer process converted the file as a text file from EBCDIC to ASCII and mangled the comp-3 fields by treating them as character data. Can you add the record layout to the question. The field names don't matter.

Comment: i added a screenshot the question....it is reflecting as a link...

Comment: I would also suggest that you create an object with the values that you want, worry about importing them into SQL Server once you can reliably create a new object and have it populated with the correct values.  Process should be input => object => sql server.  You need to concentrate on getting the bugs out of setting the right values on your object before worrying about sql.

Comment: @Kris. the record layout helps. It looks like the sample 0x0200EAA4 value is `REC_DATE`. Do you know if the date format is YYMMDD? What code page was used to create the file and what code page are you using to read it?

Comment: @DanGuzman glad it helped, what do you meant by code page, could you please elaborate.

Comment: @Kris, non-Unicode text files are encoded with a [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) specification during creation, which may be the source system default one. That same code page should be used when reading data from the file to avoid character loss. The code page can be specified in the SSIS file connection source. I suspect the comp-3 binary data was mangled because the it the data was treated as text instead of binary and encoded improperly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Current File

0x0200EAA4 converted into EBCDIC is x0200529F which is a valid comp-3 value (2020-May-29).

Running an ascii conversion on a binary EBCDIC file (like this file) **will corrupt** the File
**Do not** try and process the current file.

### Solutions

- Convert the file to Text on the source compute (Mainframe ??) and transmit/translate the file
- If processing a *Mainframe Cobol* File have a look at [cb2xml](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cb2xml/). It will convert a Cobol Copybook into a Xml file (and calculate position / length). The Xml can be processed in many languages.
- Convert to fixed length on source compute (probably is already Fixed length) and transfer 
  as an **EBCDIC** file. The file will not have any carriage return line-Feed characters in it.
  You would need to process it as an EBCDIC file.

If you can

- run java
- Get the Cobol Copybook
- There are **no redefines** in the Cobol copybook

Some thing like [CobolToCsv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/coboltocsv/) can convert the file from Cobol-Ebcdic into an Ascii-Csv file

---

### EBCDIC

There are multiple EBCDIC character-sets Cp037/IBM037 is US EBCDIC; CP273/IBM273 is German EBCDIC you will need to find out which EBCDIC dialect is being used

**Note:** CP037 stands for Coded-Page 037

### Mainframe Fixed width

With mainframe fixed width, all records are the **same length** and there
are no Carriage Return / Line Feed characters.
For a file with 26 byte records it is

```
<-- 26 bytes --><-- 26 bytes --> ... <-- 26 bytes -->
```

### cb2xml

[cb2xml](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cb2xml/) will convert a Cobol Copybook to xml. This allows for generic processing of Cobol data in most modern languages

cb2xml will convert

```
 01 Location-Record.
     03 Record-Type            pic xx.
     03 location occurs 10.
        05 DC-Number           pic 9(4).
        05 Pack-Quantity       pic 9(8).
```

to

```
<item display-length="122" level="01" name="Location-Record" position="1" storage-length="122">
    <item display-length="2" level="03" name="Record-Type" picture="xx" position="1" storage-length="2"/>
    <item display-length="12" level="03" name="location" occurs="10" position="3" storage-length="12">
        <item display-length="4" level="05" name="DC-Number" numeric="true" picture="9(4)" position="3" storage-length="4"/>
        <item display-length="8" level="05" name="Pack-Quantity" numeric="true" picture="9(8)" position="7" storage-length="8"/>
    </item>
</item>
```

Comment: @Kris, I see BruceMartin distilled our comments into an answer. When binary data are accidentally encoded as text, one cannot perform a reliable round-trip conversion to get the original binary value because there might not be a corresponding character in the code page used for encoding, corrupting the binary value permanently.

Comment: Adding a PS snippet that shows the value converted from ASCII back to EBCDIC, guessing at the code pages: `[Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(37).GetBytes([Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252).GetChars((0x02,0x00,0xEA,0xA4))) | Format-Hex`

Comment: @Bruce Martin ...thanks for your response. Yes, It'a mainframe system and are fixed length. We have asked them to convert the file at the source now as EBCDIC file, from your suggestion.

Comment: @Kris expanded the answer a little, added a cb2xml section